How to find the capital 'R's and replace with lowercase 'r's | Excel on Mac
How to find the capital 'R's and replace with lowercase 'r's across all cells in a worksheet. The Rs are within words. Excel on Mac.

Which software? What OS? Have you looked to see if the search function has a "Case Sensitive" option somewhere in its interface? Please note that there is a LOT of software out there that you MAY be asking about, and that we only know what you tell us explicitly in this question. Do not add further info down here as comment, but add all requested info to the question itself using the EDIT button.

Did you see the "Match Case" option in Excel on Mac? A quick web search told me that is what it is called in the Mac version of this software.

=SUBSTITUTE(range,"R","r") ?

A quick web search tells me the Case Sensitive option in the Find dialog in Excel on a Mac is called "Match Case".
Open the Find dialog, be in the Find and Replace section, enable the Match Case option, enter the upper-case "R" as what you want to find, and enter the lowercase "r" as what you want to replace it with, and then allow the process to run.

The Rs are a part of words, so Excel doesn't select it because there are other letters on either side of the R. I need to tell Excel to look for an R - anywhere, in any cell, between other letters, at the front and end of words etc. - and replace it with an r.

Did you highlight the cells you're trying to search? Excel on Windows finds single characters within words just fine.

I did. I also tested with a cell with a single R in it and Excel found it and changed it. It just can't seem to find the Rs in  tRees, Ramp and eRode etc.

Is the set of words with capital Rs finite? How large is the dataset? If you know the words that will have these capital characters, can you simply find and replace the entire words?

Works fine for me on a Mac, are you sure you have the "Find Entire Cells Only" option unchecked?
